# Rename a tag with misspelled name

Tags: support, tags

Following this post ([How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag)), may I ask a moderator to rename a tag I created on Stack Overflow? I misspelled the name of a R package. [envstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envstat) should be [envstats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envstats).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the tag was just created by you, and has very few questions, you can handle it yourself in the following way:

1. Remove that tag from all questions
2. Wait for a day. The tag should then be deleted
3. Create the correct tag
4. Add the tag back to all questions

Comment: @www I've renamed it anyway - will save any issues with plural tag names and people following the tag as it's named now will end up following the new one automatically.